# What are the different ways to initiate an android phone erase

Tags: nexus-5, factory-reset, 6.0-marshmallow

This morning I woke up without my alarm.
My alarm hadn't gone off because my phone wasn't working.

On the screen I had a message "Erasing...".

[image: Erasing]
<sup>The screen looked similar to this (source: [AndroidPIT](https://fs02.androidpit.info/userfiles/4774964/image/Q2-2015/AndroidPIT-Moto-X-hero-erasing-w782.jpg))</sup>

After a while my phone booted up, without any user data.

I've had a restless night with a baby that needed frequent changing, and spent a lot of time checking the time on my phone.
It is wholly possible that I did something / held some buttons down.

My question is, what could I have done?
How did I possibly start the erasing procedure?

Comment: Google phone_name_and_model factory reset, 
"Galaxy S6 factory reset" to get a few sites explaining all the possible ways to reset the phone, yes button combo is one of the options.

Comment: @ИвоНедев I did, but I got a lot of different examples, some of which didn't apply, or were outdated. So I figured it would make for a nice question here. Especially considering some of the examples did not result in an "erasing"  screen. If you think this question isn't a good fit here, let me know.

Comment: @Reaces "Erasing" is usually shown when you triggered the factory-reset via *Settings*. If you did it via the recovery menu, it usually shows "Deleting" or "Wiping". To decide which place it was it would help if you could tell us whether it was a graphical or rather a text-mode screen shown.

Comment: @Izzy It was a graphical screen, similar to [this](https://fs02.androidpit.info/userfiles/4774964/image/Q2-2015/AndroidPIT-Moto-X-hero-erasing-w782.jpg).

Comment: That looks like a factory-reset initialized via the recovery menu. But it might well be the same thing is triggered by *Settings › Backup & Reset*.

Comment: @Izzy That seems pretty elaborate for something I did while literally asleep... Is there something else that could trigger this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The most likely scenario I can imagine is you've opened settings, got into *Backup & Reset*, and triggered a factory-reset from there. Being half-asleep, I can hardly imagine you've managed booting into recovery, scrolled to "factory reset" using the volume rockers, hit the power-button to confirm, managed to pick the one "Yes" entry among the 9 "No", and hit the power button again :)